# ng-click toggle with double statements

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that shows a list of movies, in each repeat is an icon that when clicked sets the current index to `model.displayedIndex`:

```
<span><i ng-click="toggle($index); model.displayedIndex = $index"></i></span>
```

And

```
    <div class="additional_info" ng-show="$index === model.displayedIndex">
        {{movie.overview}}
    </div>>
```

When the icon is clicked the ng-show checks if the `$index === model.displayedIndex` if the value is the same the statement is true and the div is shown. This way only the ng-show inside the ng-repeat is true.

But now I'm looking for a way to toggle the ng-show when clicked on the same icon. Now nothing happens since the value model.displayedIndex is equal to index. How would I set the ng-show to false in this case?

I've tried adding the following to my icon:

```
<span><i ng-click="toggle($index); model.displayedIndex = $index ; toggleInfo = !toggleInfo"></i></span>
```

And in my div:

```
<div class="additional_info" ng-show="$index === model.displayedIndex || toggleInfo">
```

But obviously the model.displayedIndex is still equal to the index so the ng-show is still set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-click` should call this function

```
$scope.toggleDisplay = function(index){
    if(index == $scope.model.displayedIndex)
        $scope.model.displayedIndex = -1;  
    else
        $scope.model.displayedIndex = index;
}
```

If you click on the current `displayedIndex` - it will set it to `-1` and then the `ng-show` condition will be `false`

Here is your span updated

```
<span><i ng-click="toggle($index); toggleDisplay($index)"></i></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It has a few small problems though. First of by removing ` model.displayedIndex = $index` from the click the model.displayIndex doesn't get an value. I fixed this but then the obvious problem is that when the function is called the if statement is true and the displayedIndex gets set to -1 which results in the ng-show being untrue and this never shown.

Comment: I dont understand your problem ? The `if` is only true when you click 2 times in a row on the same span

Comment: Hm. I don't see what the `toggle($index);` in the ng-click is for. Does that do anything? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This method was in your question and you did not mention anything about it. I don't know what it is used for. I thought it was something not linked to your question.

Comment: So. It works! You made a small typo in the `if`' statement you typed `dislayedIndex` instead of `displayedIndex` (you missed a p) thus the if statement was never called. It's a very nice sollution thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: Oops sorry for that ! I am glad that I could help you ! Dont forget to mark it as the answer for the future viewer